# Laravel 4 controllers and routes

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

Heloo, im making a laraver 4 app for first time and some things i still dont understand, one of them are the controllers:

At laraver 3 i could do something like:

```
Route::get('/',array('uses'=>'home@index'));
```

and at the controller:

```
public function get_index(){
    return 'hello';
}
```

But now at laravel 4 i have something like:

```
class HomeController extends BaseController {

    public function showWelcome()
    {
        return View::make('home.main');
    }

}
```

First in this file could i change HomeController to Home only?
The how could i make the controller restful?

And at the routes:

```
Route::get('/', array('uses'=>'HomeController@Welcome'));
```

How can i call it, it's not working.

Didn't understand at all laravel 4 documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's already RESTful, you just had a small bug on your route, try this:

```
Route::get('/', array('uses'=>'HomeController@showWelcome'));
```

In the uses you must have `ControllerName@methodName`, so it's `showWelcome` in your case, not just `Welcome`.

Also, you can change it to Home, but you better stick with the name HomeController (or AnythingController), unless you have a very good reason for that.

Comment: Take a look at your routes doing `php artisan routes`

Comment: Looks like a group of routes was "canceling" the index route, why could it be?

Comment: Not sure. I just did the same to mine (http://puu.sh/37Sja.png) and it worked just fine: http://puu.sh/37Sln.png.

Comment: Ok i will look at it, if found somethig i'll let you know

Answer (score 3):

The method `showWelcome` is not RESTful and as such it has a route that maps to it directly. If you want your methods on `HomeController` to be prefixed with the HTTP verb they respond to, such as `get`, `post`, `put`, then you need to register the controller with `Route::controller`.

```
Route::controller('/', 'HomeController');
```

You should then rename the method to `getWelcome` and you would browse to it by hitting `localhost/yourapp/welcome`. You'd use `getIndex` if you wanted to hit `localhost/yourapp`.